# Question applying Gauss' theorem

Tags: integration

Q: Use Gauss' theorem to compute the surface integral
$$
\oint_{S}{\bf r}\cdot{\bf n}\ {\rm d}S
$$
where $S$ is the surface of the unit cube $0 \leq x, y, z \leq 1$ where ${\bf r}$ is the position vector.

Not sure how to apply this, obviously
${\bf r} = \left(x,y,z\right)$ but I'm not sure how to parametrise the surface of the unit cube in this instance $?$. Any help $?$.

Comment: If you're using Gauss' Theorem, you don't need to parameterize the surface of the cube. See the answer someone posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Gauss's theorem
$$\oint_{S}{\bf r}\cdot{\bf n}\ {\rm d}S = \int_V \nabla\cdot{\bf r}\  dV$$

Now, by going to Cartesian coordinates, we get
$$\nabla\cdot{\bf r} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial z} = 3$$

Hence,
$$\oint_{S}{\bf r}\cdot{\bf n}\ {\rm d}S = \int_V 3 \ dV = 3$$